# How to create an optional instance of a case class?

Tags: scala

Suppose I've got `case class A(os: Option[String], ox: Option[Int], oy: Option[Int])` and need a function `(Option[String], Option[Int], Option[Int]) => Option[A]` to return `None` if all the arguments are `None` and `Some[A]` otherwise: e.g.

```
def foo(os: Option[String], ox: Option[Int], oy: Option[Int]): Option[A] = ???

foo(Some("abc"), Some(1), Some(2)) // Some(A(Some("abc"), Some(1), Some(2))
foo(Some("abc"), None, None)       // Some(A(Some("abc"), None, None))
foo(None, None, None)              // None
```

How would you write `foo` ?

Comment: What's `A`? Is it parameterized at class level? Did you forget to parameterize the method?

Comment: `A` is a class class. Renamed and modified the question.

Comment: How do you create an instance of `A`?

Comment: `val a = A(Some("xyz"), None, None)`

Comment: A case class with all properties optional is a symptom that is would be better represented using AST/sealed family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe naive, but works...

```
def foo(os: Option[String], ox: Option[Int], oy: Option[Int]): Option[A] = 
  (os, ox, oy) match {
    case (None, None, None) => None
    case (x, y, z) => Some(A(x, y, z))
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

use matching:

```
(os, ox, oy) match {
    case (None, None, None) => None
    case _ => Some(A(os, ox, oy))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variation :

```
def foo(os: Option[String], ox: Option[Int], oy: Option[Int]): Option[A] =
  if (Seq(os, ox, oy).forall(_.isEmpty)) None
  else Some(A(os, ox, oy))
```

Another variation:

```
def foo(os: Option[String], ox: Option[Int], oy: Option[Int]): Option[A] = 
     Seq(os, ox, oy).find(_.isDefined).fold[Option[A]](None)(_ => Some(A(os,ox,oy)))
```

Answer (score -2):

With `flatMap`

```
class A(o1: Option[String], o2: Option[Int], o3: Option[Int])

  def foo(o1: Option[String], o2: Option[Int], o3: Option[Int]): Option[A] = {
    o1.flatMap(x => o2.flatMap(b => o3.flatMap(c => Some(new A(Some(x), o2, o3)))))
  }
```

With a for comphreension

```
 class A(o1: Option[String], o2: Option[Int], o3: Option[Int])

  def foo(o1: Option[String], o2: Option[Int], o3: Option[Int]): Option[A] = {
   (for {
     a1 <- o1
     a2 <- o2
     a3 <- o3
   } yield Some(new A(Some(a1), o2, o3))).flatten
  }
```

Pattern matching was already suggested, so I won't post it here

Comment: Neither of these solutions produces the correct result for `foo(Some("abc"), Some(1), Some(2))`

Comment: Nope, still wrong :) Is it hard to paste your code in repl, and see if it compiles before hitting "Submit"? At this time it doesn't. But, even if you fix the compile errors, it's not doing what OP is was asking.

Comment: @FredericA. no because those are the values wrapped by the `Option`s. @Dima it compiled at first but was passing `None` to the second and third parameter (something that doesn't invalidate the response). So many downvotes for a solution that works (yes, it was updated twice) ... Amusing :)